# Help on Exploitable response

Tags: exploit, windbg

I have a crash that is exploitable, the information is this:

```
  Exploitability Classification: EXPLOITABLE
    Recommended Bug Title: Exploitable - User Mode Write AV starting at myfunction!mycomponet+0x0000000000018204 (Hash=0xad0842a8.0x0as0d4ca)

User mode write access violations that are not near NULL are exploitable.
```

I only have experience on stack overflow, and here don't see eip overwrite.

I know that fault, is when pass to vulnerable function a value greater than 80000001, the crash occurs.

But I don't know which type of vulnerability is it, heap overflow, integer, format string , command injection etc..

My question, with the exploitable response indicate the vulnerabilities ??? 
I don't understand the exploitable response.

Any suggestion or indication ?

Sorry for my newbie question, I am a beginner in exploiting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was classified as exploitable because it's a write access-violation to a non-null address. In theory, an attacker may be able to exploit this vulnerability to write arbitrary code to an arbitrary address.

Comment: Yes, thanks, but how exploit it? which vuln is? need learn about this vuln, I don't know.

Thanks for your time and fast response Jason Geffner :-)

Comment: That's a different question. Best to start a new one.

Comment: @spider-45 A vulnerability does not need to turn into code execution. If you can set specific variables you can also trigger vulnerabilities. Eg 'userid'

Comment: Thanks for advice @Stolas, and Jason Geffner for corretions.